# Placeholder do TextInput quebrando após digitar

Tags: javascript, react-native

Tenho um `TextInput` que quando inicia funciona normal, mas após o usuário digitar algo e apagar, o placeholder quebra em duas linhas.

**Ao iniciar a tela**

[image: Ao iniciar]

**Depois de digitar e apagar**

[image: Digitar e apagar]

```js
<TextInput
  editable
  placeholder='FAÇA UMA BUSCA EM TODO SISTEMA'
  placeholderTextColor={COLORS.DUSTY_GRAY}
  ref={inputRef}
  returnKeyType='search'
  style={styles.input}
  value={value}
/>
```

```js
input: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 14,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    color: COLORS.DUSTY_GRAY,
},
```